# OrgShape for unlocked packages with encrypted fields

Tags: scratch-org, unlocked-package

OrgShape is a brilliant concept and useful in many ways especially for larger orgs.

Unfortunately, creating unlocked packages fails when a repo has encrypted fields. It also fails while creating scratch orgs for feature development.

In the latter scenario there is a workaround by using scripts. However, it doesn't work when we want to create unlocked packages. Because the process of creating unlocked packages uses a scratch org that cannot be accessed by automation scripts.

How can we create unlocked packages having encrypted fields via org shaped scratch org please?

Thanks
Neel

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Enable Shield Encryption (in any scratch org)
2. Encrypt a field  (in any scratch org) (CaseSensitiveDeterministicEncryption)
3. Pull changes to your repo
4. Update your scratch org definition to use Org Shape. The Org Shape should be of Unlimited Edition
5. Create an unlocked package from your repo

The unlocked package creation fails with the below error.

*You don't have permission to change Encryption Policy settings. Contact your Salesforce admin to request access*

But, if you change your scratch org definition file to create a "Developer Edition" org... the unlocked package gets created successfully.

Comment: Did you try to [Specify Unpackaged Metadata or Apex Access for Package Version Creation Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm)?

Comment: Are you able to share a minimal example of something you can’t package? I’m not sure I understand the OrgShape link.

Comment: Hello @DavidReed - Sorry, that I was not clear earlier. Let me add the steps in the above question

Comment: I'm not especially surprised that this fails, although the error message is a bit confusing. If you're going to use Org Shape, I would recommend enabling encryption in the Org Shape before you try to deploy this metadata.

You may need to swap to building an Org-Dependent Package.

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestion. When you say enable encryption in the Org Shape... you mean in the Scratch Org that is created based on Org Shape right? If yes, then we will not have access to the Scratch Org that gets created implicitly during package creation. Let me know if I am missing something or if there is a way to access that Scratch Org.